# pg_prepare with variable number of parameters

Tags: php, postgresql, prepared-statement

Is it possible to use `pg_prepare()` with a variable number of parameters?

Example:

```
session_start();
$parameters = array($_SESSION['foo']);
$strsql ='select * from table where user=$1';

if (isset($_REQUEST['a'])) {
  $strsql .= ' and abc=$2';
  array_push($parameters, $_REQUEST['a']);
} 

if (isset($_REQUEST['b'])) {
  $strsql .= ' and def=$3';
  array_push($parameters, $_REQUEST['b']);
}

$res = pg_prepare($con, "test", $strsql);
$res = pg_execute($con, "test", $parameters);
```

This does not work as all parameters have to be set.

Is there a better way to implement this sort of query building?